# How can I filter the values retrieved during ngOnInit and display them on the screen?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material

I want to display those fastFoodShopList, bakeryShopList, generalStoreList variables on screen, but not display on screen.

I've confirmed that the value is being retrieved using console.log, but it seems that the screen is being displayed before that.

How can I display these variables on the screen?

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loaderService
      .loadShopList(userInfo)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy$))
      .subscribe((shopTypeList) => {
        this.fastFoodShopList = shopTypeList.filter((shop) => shop.type === 'fastFood')[0].shopList;
        this.bakeryShopList = shopTypeList.filter((shop) => shop.type === 'bakery')[0].shopList;
        this.generalStoreList = shopTypeList.filter((comment) => shop.type === 'generalStore')[0].shopList;
      });
  }
```

HTML is like this.

```
 <div *ngFor="let fastFoodShop of this.fastFoodShopList; index as i">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <p>{{ fastFoodShop.shopName }}</p>
            <p>{{ fastFoodShop.memo }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove `this` from the ngFor directive

Comment: I removed `this` but nothing change.

Comment: If you write `{{ fastFoodShopList | json }}` somewhere in the html, do you display anything?

Comment: no. I can't see json data on screen.

Comment: Then the problem is on your service, you’re not retrieving/passing the data. Can you include it in your question?

Comment: but I've confirmed that the value is being retrieved using console.log. The data is not reflected on the screen.　 I think I need to use rxjs filter in parallel...

Comment: Where have you logged it? Have you did something like `.pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy$), tap(v => console.log(v)))`?

Comment: I just tried that. and I've confirmed that the data has been acquired.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself.

I needed markForCheck();

```
  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef)

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loaderService
      .loadShopList(userInfo)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy$))
      .subscribe((shopTypeList) => {
        this.fastFoodShopList = shopTypeList.filter((shop) => shop.type === 'fastFood')[0].shopList;
        this.bakeryShopList = shopTypeList.filter((shop) => shop.type === 'bakery')[0].shopList;
        this.generalStoreList = shopTypeList.filter((comment) => shop.type === 'generalStore')[0].shopList;
        this.cd.markForCheck();
      });
  }
```

Comment: If that was the problem, you should either refactor your code into push-based architecture or set the change detection on default.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using async pipe in your template

```
const fastFoodShopList: Observable

  this.fastFoodShopList = this.loaderService
      .loadShopList(userInfo)
      .pipe(map((shopTypeList) => { return {shopname:....,memo:...} ) );

 <div *ngFor="let fastFoodShop of fastFoodShopList | async">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <p>{{ fastFoodShop.shopName }}</p>
            <p>{{ fastFoodShop.memo }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```